# Specifying while condition causes program to return nothing

Tags: java, if-statement, hash, while-loop, brute-force

I'm currently working on a brute-force password cracking method because I want to try it out and do something new. I'm providing the methods I'm working on below but here's first what I'm trying to do. Initially, I'm generating the hash of a possible value for the password and comparing it against the one I have in my "sample.txt" file that contains a list of hashed passwords. So basically my goal is to read the hashed password value from that external file and compare it against all possible 3/4 hashed password values.

When I ran the program, I accidentally kept the condition of the while statement in the "BruteForce" method to true and it endlessly ran, however when I set the condition to keeping the password value generated to be having a length of 3 and 4 only, the program suddenly terminates I don't know why, I've tried debugging the program to see where things go wrong but i was not able to deduce anything.

Here's what's in my main method and the "bruteforce" method :

```
public TestClass(char[] characterSet, int guessLength) {
    cs = characterSet;
    cg = new char[guessLength];
    Arrays.fill(cg, cs[0]);
}

public static void bruteForce(String username, String hashed_pw) {

      //username is the username from the input
      //hashed_pw is the hashed value of password
    String chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char[] charset = chars.toCharArray();

    TestClass bf = new TestClass(charset, 1); //random generation of possible pw value

    String attempt = bf.toString();

    while ((attempt.length() == 3) || (attempt.length() == 4)) {

        String hashed_input = doHash(attempt); //hash the possible pw value

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Attempt result is: " + attempt);
        System.out.println("Hashed of attempt: " + hashed_input);
        System.out.println("Hashed Password is : " + hashed_pw);
        System.out.println("");

        if (hashed_input.equals(hashed_pw)) {
            System.out.println("Password Found: " + attempt);
            System.out.println(username + "'s password is: " + attempt);
            break;
        } else {
            attempt = bf.toString();
            bf.increment();
        }
        // attempt = bf.toString();
        // System.out.println("" + attempt);
        //  bf.increment();
        // return attempt;

    }
    // return attempt;
}

public char[] cs; 
public char[] cg; 


public void increment() {
    int index = cg.length - 1;
    while (index >= 0) {
        if (cg[index] == cs[cs.length - 1]) {
            if (index == 0) {
                cg = new char[cg.length + 1];
                Arrays.fill(cg, cs[0]);
                break;
            } else {
                cg[index] = cs[0];
                index--;
            }
        } else {
            cg[index] = cs[Arrays.binarySearch(cs, cg[index]) + 1];
            break;
        }
    }
}

  @Override
 public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(cg);
}
```

When running the code with bruteForce(s[0],s[1]) it does not provide any output but only gives the BUILD SUCCESSFUL message.

```
s[0]  is the username of the user I'm trying to deduce their password
s[1] is the hashed password I read from an external file
```

I compare the s[1] value against the hashed_input value in the bruteForce method, with the condition that the possibly generated password of my user has a length of 3 or 4 characters only

Comment: How can something be equal to 3 AND 4 at the same time?

Comment: @Tunaki that was a typo from my side, what I meant to say is equal to 3 OR 4

Comment: Look at your code, this is what it does....

Comment: Now you can start making a [mcve].

Comment: I've seen, comment removed

Comment: Your title still says "AND" by the way. Take your time to write the question...

Comment: by the way, I cannot understand where your `attempt` variable change inside the loop

Comment: Simple assumption: Whatever is constructed in `TestClass` (and returned by its `toString` method) is not of length 3 or 4.

Comment: @FMiscia it changes in the else statement, under attempt = bf.toString(), then bf.increment() happens and yes I did override the toString method

Comment: @Tunaki thank you for your patience, I did carefully edit my question just now

Comment: What exactly is your `toString` method returning?

Comment: @UnholySheep return String.valueOf(cg);

Comment: So let me summarize: You are creating a `char` array of length 1 and comparing whether its length is equal to 3 or 4 and are confused that is not the case?

Comment: how can you enter in the loop if `cg` has length 1?

Comment: You initialize TrstClass with length 1. So after you call to string on it you get string with length equal to 1("0" in fact).

Comment: @UnholySheep could you elaborate ? Because my charset array is created from the "char" string of characters.

Comment: @talex the value increments when the program start to run in the bruteForce method

Comment: `cg = new char[guessLength];` This is your array. You are passing a value of 1 for `guessLength`. What makes you believe you are creating an array of length 3 or 4?

Comment: change it in a do { }while() if you want to get in the loop

Comment: @Scarl yes, inside the loop, but you newer get there.

Comment: @FMiscia with the same while condition, I've changed it to do {} while() but it's still not returning anything

Comment: @talex so you're saying I should not initialise it to any value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TestClass bf = new TestClass(charset, 3);
```

Will solwe your problem.